# How to solve Hoffman & Kunze exercise 1, section 3.5

Tags: linear-algebra

> In $R^3$,  let $v_1=(1,0,1), v_2= (0,1,-2), v_3= (-1,-1,0)$
>
> If $f$ is a linear functional on $R^3$ such that $f(v_1)=1, f(v_2)=-1,f(v_3)=3,$
> and if $\alpha = (a,b,c)$, find $f(\alpha)$ .

I know that from this what I have to do is $f(a,b,c)=af(e_1)+bf(e_2)+cf(e_3)$
But I do not know how to find each $f(e_i)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a basis for $\Bbb{R}^3$, we first write $(a,b,c)$ as a linear combination of $v_i$'s **not $e_i$'s** because $v_i$'s are given and its function values are also given, so we use that!

Write $$(a,b,c)=a_1(1,0,1)+a_2(0,1,-2)+a_3(-1,-1,0)$$

We have to find $a_1,a_2,a_3$. The above equation leads to $$a=a_1-a_3$$ $$b=a_2-a_3$$ $$c=a_1-2a_2$$

Solving these to get  $$a_1=2a-2b-c$$ $$a_2=a-b-c$$ $$a_3=a-2b-c$$ [Verify this part by yourself!]

Can you conclude now?